# best solution for strange language chats

Tags: clash-of-clans

While playing most of massively multilayer games we come across "virutal" individuals that are either characters or a leader of a base. So when players chat they are expected to communicate in a language understood by most of the people in that specific chat room.

For instance I recently had this chat in clash of clans. I have this screenshot. The player wants to chat but the meaning of his sentence is rarely understood by any member of our clan. I am sure that many clashers out there are facing same problem and it is not only this game I had faced problem in other game.

One solution would be to leave the clan and join another clan. But why should I leave my clan just because of one player talking senseless words?

Another solution is to kick him, but by kicking player we lose valuable player like him (he tends to stay active in wars and plays the game very well).

So **I want to ask what is the best method to deal with great but senseless speaking players?**

I would not like to go with either of solutions that I mentioned above, is there any better way to keep things well balanced.

---

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to deal with people. It's in the context of a game, but it's not a gaming issue. It's psychology.

Comment: I believe the language they are speaking is Malay. Try using something like google translate to translate what they say and what you want to say back if you wish to communicate with them.

Comment: @Frank psychology, hmm. so where is the appropriate place to ask this question?

Comment: It's not super on-topic, but I don't think there's a better SE. I would consider this equivalent to discussing issues with communication while playing DnD, which is a huge topic on RPG SE. The important thing is that the communication is occurring through the game, and directly impacts the game. It's not a question about how to deal with foreign speaking people at the gas station.

Comment: I voted to close as 'primarily opinion-based' instead of off-topic. (The 'too broad' close reason will also probably fit.) Even if on-topic here, I believe this type of question is more suited to a discussion forum instead of a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a couple of considerations.

One is, how much do you like your clan?  Is it a clan where your friends are, or where you've made friends?  If you have no real attachment, and foreign language "spam" bothers you, go find an English only clan.  Lots of them exist.

If you're attached to your clan, are you short on clan/war slots?  Chances are this is a no, although you might be leaving folks out of war owing to this, which might make you want to kick the person.

Do you have difficulty communicating, and is that impacting your in-game performance?  For instance, does this person coordinate well during wars?  If not, they're a liability and should be kicked.

Beyond that, you've basically just got to put up with it.  You could try figuring out what language they're speaking and learn a few key words, although chances are good they're going to use slang, abbreviate, or misspell things, and that's going to make any sort of discussion super tricky.